A question of some maximal inequality for random process
I am reading Probability in High Dimension by Ramon van Handel Chapter 5 of Suprema. I have some trouble with understanding the following lemma (Lemma 5.1 in the book). Here $\{X_t\}_{t\in T}$ is a random proecess defined on some index set $T$.

The right hand quantity is upper bounded by $\inf_{\lambda > 0}\frac{\log\vert T\vert + \psi(\lambda)}{\lambda}$, which is argued to be equal to $\psi^{\star -1}(\log\vert T\vert)$.

I understand the fact that $\psi^\star$ is invertible, what I do not understand is that why $\psi^\star(z) = \log(\vert T\vert)$. Can some one please help me understand this?
Thanks.

Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.
